# How to deserialize different xml-tags into a single list

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have xml that looks something like this

```
<root>
    <bosses>
        <boss>..some elements..</boss>
        <boss>..some elements..</boss>
    </bosses>
    <workers>
        <worker>..some elements..not the same as bosses</worker>
        <worker>..some elements..</worker>
    </workers>
</root>
```

and a few classes that look something like this

```
public class Person
{
    //properties common to both bosses and workers
}

public class Boss : Person
{
    //some properties unique for bosses
}

public class Worker : Person
{
    //some properties unique for workers        
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is deserialize the xml into a single `List<Person>`, but quite frankly I am stumped on how to do that.

I can get separate lists for bosses and workers by doing

```
    [XmlElement("bosses")]
    public List<Boss> Bosses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("workers")]
    public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
```

I've tried combining them naively by doing this

```
    [XmlElement("bosses")]
    [XmlElement("workers")]
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
```

but it fails. If I had to take a guess it would be that I have to tell the dezerializer which subclass of `Person` to use with bosses and which to use with workers, but even if that is the case, I cant seem to find how that is done.

So, please enlighten me!

EDIT (solution): What do you know, asking the question triggered some new thoughts and I was able to figure out the solution. I'll post it here in case someone else comes looking with similar issues:

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "bosses", Type = typeof(Boss))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "workers", Type = typeof(Worker))]
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
```

Comment: Take a look at `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes

Comment: The quick way is to make a new list of person and add both lists to this

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "bosses", Type = typeof(Boss))]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "workers", Type = typeof(Worker))]
public List<Person> People { get; set; }
```